# How do I get the calendars from the Harvard GSD using Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, calendar

I'm trying to set this up through Ajax, and this is what I have so far. I've been trying to figure this out for a while and can't seem to get something to click.

```
function getFunction()
{
$(".cals").click(function()
{
    $.get("http://events.cs50.net/api/1.0/calendars?campus=GSD&output=json", function(data, status) 
    {

        var response = "<h3>GSD Calenders</h3>\n";


        response = response + '<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true">\n';

        var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data);
        for (var i = 0; i < jsonObject.length; i++) {
            var calendar = jsonObject[i].calname;
            response = response
                + '<li><a href="#item">'
                + calendar
                + '</a></li>\n'; }


        response = response + '</ul>';


        $('#calendars').html(response);
    });
});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/rW9gx/1/

I have changed the js to this:

```
$(function() {

    $("#cals").click(function()
    {
        $.getJSON("http://events.cs50.net/api/1.0/calendars?campus=GSD&output=json", function(data, status) 
        {

        var response = "<h3>GSD Calenders</h3>\n";
        response = response + '<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true">\n';

            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var calendar = data[i].calname;
                response = response
                    + '<li><a href="#item">'
                    + calendar
                    + '</a></li>\n'; 
            }
            response = response + '</ul>';
            $('#calendars').html(response);
        });
    });

});
```

A few things:

You have wrapped your click event handler in a function (`getFunction`) which means that the handler will only be applied after that is fired. I don't know if that is intended or not, or if your code sample is full or not, but in the fiddle I have removed it and wrapped the js up in a document ready function so that it will be applied when the DOM has loaded.

I changed the json `$.get` to a `$.getJSON`, which is just a shortcut of writing `dataType: "json"` in an `$.ajax` or `$.get` call. This means you don't have to parse the return data as Json as that is what you will expect back.

Otherwise it was working just fine.

Comment: Thank you greatly! I couldn't figure out what was not working or what I was missing. Thanks!